# Web API with OData and Entity Framework - Serialization Issue

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

In my `Web API` app, if I use `OData` in a Get method to filter the results, I get back inconsistent results.  Without the `OData` filter, the result is fine.  *Is serialization handled differently when using OData?* *Am I doing this the right way?*

With OData:

[image]

*I don't understand what the $ref entries are, why are they random, and why don't I get them when not using `OData`??*

Here's the `Web API` method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions<Employee> options)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            var employees = options.ApplyTo(_unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.Get());

            if (employees == null)
            {
                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            else
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employees);
                response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Here's the class to be serialized:

```
 public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public string WinId { get; set; }
        public string XML { get; set; }
        public int EffectiveYear { get; set; }
        public int FileKeeperGroupId { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT 8/15**

Here's my WebApiConfig

```
 var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(json);
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = 
                Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

Comment: Not clear your meaning of using OData? You mean use ODataController instead of ApiController? Can you also show the code that you use OData ?

Answer (score 1):

**Deprecated Answer:** 

As discussed in this topic [Entity relations in odata-v4](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4) please look at the section:

Creating a Relationship Between Entities

> OData supports creating or removing relationships between two existing
>   entities. In OData v4 terminology, the relationship is a "reference".
>   (In OData v3, the relationship was called a link. The protocol
>   differences don't matter for this tutorial.)
>
> A reference has its own URI, with the form
>   /Entity/NavigationProperty/$ref. For example, here is the URI to
>   address the reference between a product and its supplier:
>
> http:/host/Products(1)/Supplier/$ref

So essentially it's odata's way of knowing which entity has a navigational property of another entity. WebApi has no idea of knowing what is what, all it does is service back the data. With OData, however, you can create client side queries within the **URL itself** rather than using linq on the backend in c# (like you would against the web api). In order for odata to query the backend correctly, it'd need to be aware of all the entities and relationships in your db context; this is done by first checking out the $metadata serviced from your ODataController. You can verify this by looking at

```
http://localhost/api/User/$metadata
```

Note: Assuming your controller is named UserController

Please read up more on odata, and get used to the idea that odata needs these extra information that surrounds your data in order to understand your database correctly. If you aren't entirely satisfied, you can always write your linq queries in c# and just stick with webapi (though you do lose out some of the advantages of odata, which you can research yourself).

**New Answer (8/15)** 
Edit: Based on the comments below, it was definitely the json serialization that caused the issue and not OData serialization. Good job on finding the settings, as this site: [PreserveReferenceHandling](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm), discusses the configurations of preserving your references in your JSON response.

We realized that $ref is used for navigation properties in OData, and we also discovered that $ref is used to track object references when serializing and deserializing json.

Personally, I'd rather leave the $ref in there, because JSON.NET is smart enough to discover circular references. If you don't believe me, check out this article: [Serializing Circular References](http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/). But this is all personal preference.

Comment: I don't have any relationships or navigation properties in my class and a ODataController is not a prerequisite for using OData.

Comment: First of all, I never said ODataController was a prerequisite. Second of all, my information is not invalid, it ALSO applies to the way you are handling OData via ODataQueryOptions. Third of all, that's the reason why you're getting these random $ref, because you don't have any navigational properties. If you did, then those random $ref would make sense. You're asking a question about $ref, but what you're really asking about why does OData bring in all this information in your data. It's telling OData that each entity you have doesn't have any nav properties. Don't be brutal.

Comment: Brutal?  I don't think so.  Your comment is more helpful, however.  If I don't have nav properties (see model), then how can I get random $ref?  Are nav properties a prerequisite?

Comment: Thanks! Nav properties are not a prerequisite. Btw, are you using Newtonsoft JSON.NET to serialize your EF? Because this might not even be an OData issue. Some serializers tend to preserve object references , so it might be caused by a circular reference instead. So to prevent crashing, $ref would probably be there to circumvent that. If you ARE serializing your EF entities directly, I'd rather create a view model first.

Comment: Check out this blog post that has the same problem you're facing. http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/ If this is indeed what's happening, I'll update my answer.

Comment: If you are not using JSON.NET, then the OData serializer is doing what the JSON.NET serializer would have done anyways. Double check your entities to make sure you don't have any circular references.

Comment: Please see my edit/update, thanks.  The PreserveReferencesHandling.None vs. PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects makes the difference in the blank $ref

Answer (score -1):

It seems from the description that you are not familiar with the OData concept (correct me if I made the wrong observation). OData is an open standard ([an OASIS standard](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=odata)) for writing RESTful services and clients and certain conventions and rules are defined in OData and they are different from other types of RESTful services. ASP.NET Web API has support for OData Version 1-3 and OData Version 4.0. If you would like to enable such support in your Web API service, you should be aware that you are writing an OData service and only OData specific clients are able to talk to your service.

Serialization is handled very differently in OData from how it's handled common Web API services. The reason is that OData has very special payload kinds that need special handling. Let's take the OData V4 JSON payload for an example. It has a lot of OData specific JSON elements and attributes that common JSON payload handler doesn't have special knowledge of.

The payload you've attached isn't an OData payload, nor is the controller action you attached an OData controller action. For writing an OData service, the [ASP.NET learning site](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api) can be referred to for details.

Comment: How does this help me?